# 'not a callable feature or js function' Error when calling JS function from feature file

Tags: javascript, java, api, testing, karate

While using Karate framework for API testing I am trying to call a method in one feature file from other like this:

```
    Scenario: Scenario description
  * def util = callonce read('UtilFunctions.feature')
  * def object = 
  """
    {"_yearsOffset":-20, "_daysOffset":0}
  """
  * def customerAge = call util.getDate(object)
  * print customerAge
```

The method just returns a date with a yearsOffset and daysOffset to move the date if desired.

When I execute this I have the following error:

```
not a callable feature or js function: [type: STRING, value: 30.03.2002]
```

Even though the value displayed in the log is correct and does what the function is asked to do, the execution fails.

Any guess? I am running out of ideas.

Comment: sorry for this kind of case the only suggestion I have is to follow this process: https://github.com/karatelabs/karate/wiki/How-to-Submit-an-Issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a guess, you don't need to use `call` when simply invoking a function:

```
* def customerAge = util.getDate(object)
```

The `call` makes things a little bit easier to read only if it is a function

```
* def fun = function(x){ return { foo: x } }
* def customerAge = call fun 'bar'
# this will also work
# def customerAge = fun('bar')
```